# deezer appcelerator module for android

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, titanium-modules, deezer

I'm creating a deezer module for titanium.

I have a problem when visualizing the login message.

here's my `DeezerAndroidModule.java` (or a significant part of it)

```
@Kroll.module(name="DeezerAndroidModule", id="deezer.android")
public class DeezerAndroidModuleModule extends KrollModule
{
    private static final String TAG = "DeezerAndroidModuleModule";
        private final String APP_ID = "xxx";
        private final static String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[]{"basic_access","offline_access","email"};
    private DeezerInterface deezerInterface;
    private     DeezerConnect connection;
        {...}
    @Kroll.method
    public void loginDeezer()
    {

        connection.authorize(deezerInterface, PERMISSIONS, new ReconnectDialogHandler());

    }
        @Kroll.method @Kroll.getProperty
    public String userId()
    {

        DeezerRequest request = new DeezerRequest( "/user/me" );
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = connection.requestSync( request );
        }//try
        catch( MalformedURLException ex ) {

        }//catch
        catch( IOException ex ) {

        }//catch
        catch (OAuthException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DeezerError e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;

    }
        {...}
    class ReconnectDialogHandler implements DialogListener {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(final Bundle values) {
            SessionStore sessionStore = new SessionStore();
            sessionStore.save( connection, deezerInterface );

        }//met

        @Override
        public void onDeezerError(final DeezerError deezerError) {

        }//met

        @Override
        public void onError(final DialogError dialogError) {

        }//met

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

        }//met

        @Override
        public void onOAuthException(OAuthException oAuthException) {

        }//met


    }
```

the problem is that when I call `loginDeezer()` function, the application throws a generic `Java Exception` without prompting the login view...

here's a logcat caption

```
W/System.err( 6737): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err( 6737):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:412)
W/System.err( 6737):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:378)
W/System.err( 6737):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.retrieveResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:1018)
W/System.err( 6737):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:512)
W/System.err( 6737):    at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:258)
W/System.err( 6737):    at com.deezer.sdk.b.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err( 6737):    at com.deezer.sdk.b.a(Unknown Source)
W/System.err( 6737):    at com.deezer.sdk.DeezerConnectImpl.requestSync(Unknown Source)
W/System.err( 6737):    at deezer.android.DeezerAndroidModuleModule.userId(DeezerAndroidModuleModule.java:84)
W/System.err( 6737):    at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.nativeFireEvent(Native Method)
W/System.err( 6737):    at org.appcelerator.kroll.runtime.v8.V8Object.fireEvent(V8Object.java:64)
W/System.err( 6737):    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.doFireEvent(KrollProxy.java:835)
W/System.err( 6737):    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollProxy.handleMessage(KrollProxy.java:1059)
W/System.err( 6737):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err( 6737):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
W/System.err( 6737):    at org.appcelerator.kroll.KrollRuntime$KrollRuntimeThread.run(KrollRuntime.java:112)
```

what's not correct in my code?

Comment: Could you post the full stack trace and error message please ?

Comment: see changes @XGouchet it seems like the .jar and .so deezer android sdk files is not loaded from the module... how to do that?

Comment: From your stack trace the jar is obviously loaded. It seems you have an SSL connection issue. Which version of the Deezer SDK are you using ?

Comment: the latest one. v0.9.3 I had no problem in the iOS version. everything was working fine.

Comment: which version of Android are you running your tests in ?

Comment: same results in 2.3.3 and 4.* with google apis. android ndk r8 (tried also with r10)

Comment: what is your android api target in your manifest and project.properties file ?

Comment: I created a repo. https://github.com/darior87/deezer-android-titanium-module (with my local paths for the libraries)

Comment: Hi, I've got trouble testing your sample, as I'm not familiar at all with Titanium and can't get it to work. Do you have the same problem when using the Deezer SDK in a native android app ?

Comment: I didn't try yet. did you? if not, I'll let you know...

Comment: Yes I did and didn't have any error, tested on devices with 2.1 and 4.3. I'm guessing maybe something in Titanium might cause this. Also are you using custom ROMs or official Android system ?

Comment: physical device on a LG smartphone with 2.3. the code in which you are running the demo is the same as mine? I mean, look only at what's inside the userID and login methods. PS. another thing it might be important is that I call these 2 methods in sequence. not in two buttons/events separately.

Comment: well you should not call them in sequence but wait for the first to return a result, and then if the authentication is complete, then call the second.

Comment: but they are synchronous requests... and iOS the version works. but I will definitely try.

Comment: the authorize method is not synchronous as it calls up a dialog for the user to log in. Only when the log in is complete, then the onComplete method of your RecconectHandler is called.

Comment: Any evolution on this problem ?

Comment: I am involved in other more hurry works/projects. as soon as I have time I will try your suggestions. thanks, man.

Comment: @XGouchet how did you do the         connection.authorize(MyActivity.this, PERMISSIONS, new ReconnectDialogHandler()); command?

I mean, how did you implement the MyActivity class? can you pass me the android project or just the file please?

Comment: ps. maybe it's easier if we continue this conversation privately so that we would not comment over and over again here (nobody would read)

Comment: Sure do you have an email where I can send you a sample project ?

Comment: darior87@yahoo.it thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem, thanks to XGouchet, just using Activities:

in DeezerModule

```
@Kroll.method
public void loginDeezer()
{       
    TiApplication appContext = TiApplication.getInstance();
    Activity act = appContext.getCurrentActivity();
    Intent myIntent = new Intent(act, DeezerInterface.class);
    act.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

and the DeezerInterface activity class would be [this](http://pastebin.com/dkR1X8Qg)